# Baked Textures Don't Look Like Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I'm having trouble baking textures: I want to bake my textures, since I'm making a simulation out of them, so I can't just render the entire scene.

I set up my UV Map and unwrapped the materials using the *Smart UV Project* option. I included the nodes in the pictures below just in case that might help.

So after the baking was finished, the actual texture seemed a whole lot darker than the render, as well as the shadows seemed misplaced. 
The scene looks like the one on bottom left:

[image]

However, in the texture viewport, the scene oddly looks like this one at the bottom left:

[image]

In my bake settings, everything is checked except *Selected to Active* and *Cage*, with a margin of 16 px.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I appreciate anyone's help in advance.

NOTE: This happened to all of the materials, I'm just showing the Dark Green material out of the 14 materials I have in this model.

[image]

Comment: Are there any objects in your scene visible to viewport but unrenderable, like light sources? Also check you terrain normals are pointing outwards

Comment: I'm using a sky texture in my World Settings that lights the scene, and an additional sun lamp. I just checked my normals which all seem to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to apply scale and rotation to all your objects

```
shift + a
```

You can't have any scales that are negative, also this is just a general practice I would advice you before rendering.
Note that sometimes you have to check if your object face normals are not inverted after applying a negative scale.

My computer has issues rendering right now but this was my result:

[image: my result]

I also set the sun strength to 2.5, but that is up to you of course.

Comment: It worked! Also, I discovered earlier that part of the reason it wasn't working too well was because some polygons were overlapping each other, but even after I fixed them it still wasn't perfect. This seemed to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help :) apply scale & rotation will be your best friend